# SolrNet - How to add query string to url

Tags: .net-core, solr, solrnet

My Solr server requires me to add some parameters to the URL (?userId=XXXX&&guid=YYYY etc).
How to add these parameters to each operation in SOLRNET?
especially when adding a document.

```
Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr/product");

ISolrOperations<Product> solrProduct = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
solrProduct.Add(new Product { Name = "Kodak EasyShare" }); // the url is http://localhost:8983/solr/product/update...
solrProduct.Commit();
```

Comment: are you indexing the documents or querying the documents? if quering you can try something like var products = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("name", "solr")); // search for "solr" in the "name" field

Comment: if you are indexing the document then try solr.Add(myDocument);
solr.Add(anotherDocument);
solr.Commit();...here myDocument can be defined as var myDocument = new Product {
        Id = "SP2514N", Manufacturer = "Samsung Electronics Co. Ltd.", Categories = new[] {  "electronics",   "hard drive",      },  Price = 92,   InStock = true,   };

Comment: I'm indexing the document . I’m use the add function like you . But I’m need to change the url that add method make . Is make the base url / update. And I need to add to this url query string ?userid=xxxxxx